# How to join 2 Arrow tables?

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

I want to Join two Arrow tables on a common attribute. Does Arrow have some C++ API to achieve the same? I did find something called HashJoin but I am not sure if that can be used to join 2 tables. Any pointers on this would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with the C++ API then a join can be achieved with an ExecPlan.  The ExecPlan API is still marked experimental but it [should have some updated documentation soon](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/12033).  An example is being added as part of [this PR](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/12110/files).  The crux of the example is:

```
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(left_source,
                        cp::MakeExecNode("scan", plan.get(), {}, l_scan_node_options));
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(right_source,
                        cp::MakeExecNode("scan", plan.get(), {}, r_scan_node_options));

  arrow::compute::HashJoinNodeOptions join_opts{arrow::compute::JoinType::INNER,
                                                /*in_left_keys=*/{"lkey"},
                                                /*in_right_keys=*/{"rkey"}};

  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(
      auto hashjoin,
      cp::MakeExecNode("hashjoin", plan.get(), {left_source, right_source}, join_opts));
```

You can check out `HashJoinNodeOptions` [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/345609b61674cedc1daa3f1bf5d6b64266b19b26/cpp/src/arrow/compute/exec/options.h#L170).

Comment: One may check here: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/streaming_execution.html#hash-join